# Why is Crunchbang saying my battery is at 64% after I unplug it from charging?

Tags: linux, laptop, battery, crunchbang

I have a weird problem with Crunchbang and it battery monitor. When I plug it and let it charge it'll tell me "Your laptop is fully charged", but when I unplug it it will immediately discharge to 64% and will discharge from that point.

The even weirder thing is that it tells me I have 3 hours from that point, which is a normal battery life for me. And when I boot into windows it does not do that. Is it a setting in Crunchbang or is the battery not calibrated right?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd certainly look into battery recalibration with a tool like tlp http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-linux-advanced-power-management.html but if that does not provide relief, odds are your battery is getting old; and, batteries don't last forever.

Comment: Thanks, it said my actual capacity was 65% of its battery design capacity. Guess it's time for a new battery.